# Getting async data from module and sending it through a route's endpoint

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, routes

I'm trying to build an API endpoint in Node.

This gets data from an external API and pushes through the result through the endpoint. This endpoint will later be used on the client side.

There's a bit of logic on the API call and I want to use it as a separate component, rather than have 60 lines of code wrapped in the `route.get(..)`

Given that this is an async problem, how can I send the `asyncRequestResult` in apiRequestModule.js to routes.js so that I can perform `res.send(asyncRequestResult)` in routes.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a function in your module that properly returns an asynchronous result.  You can do that with either a callback function as an argument or by returning a promise.  Just look at every async function in the node.js library for examples everywhere on how to return an asynchronous result.

Then, your route calls the async function and when the result is returned, it then sends it as the response to the request.

**Using a Callback**

```
app.get('/somasyncrequest', function(req, res) {
   myOwnModuleCall(someArg, function(err, result) {
       if (err) {
           console.log(err);
           res.status(500).end();
       } else {
           res.send(result);
       }
   });
});
```

**Using a Promise**

```
app.get('/somasyncrequest', function(req, res) {
   myOwnModuleCall(someArg).then(function(result) {
       res.send(result);
   }, function(err) {
       console.log(err);
       res.status(500).end();
   });
});
```

Then, in the implementation of `myOwnModuleCall()`, when the async response is done, you either call the passed in callback (first example) or resolve/reject the promise (second example).

Comment: Of course so put the anonymous callback in the function call, forgot that was possible. Will try that tomorrow thanks

Comment: I'm having another issue with passing that callback through my code. I think I'll create a new question because I don't understand the paradigm of the function I've used, which is from another library

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37049067/cant-successfully-pass-through-a-callback-into-a-function-chain