# Can't successfully pass through a callback into a function chain

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, callback

I'm using the codebird library to perform some requests to the Twitter API. These requests respond correctly but I want to pass that response through to my route. Here is a snippet of my route.js:

```
router.get('/twitter', function(req, res) {

  twitterAPI.callAPI(function(tweetData) {
    console.log('callback for twitterCall');
    res.send(tweetData);
  });

});
```

This is my code from module1.js:

```
require('es6-promise').polyfill();
require('isomorphic-fetch');
var Codebird = require("codebird");

// using twitter-aggregation app for consumer key and secret
var params = {
  screen_name: 'kanyewest'
};

var config = {
  twitter : {
    consumerKey: 'thisismykey',
    consumerSecret: 'thisismysecret'
  }
};

var cb = new Codebird;
cb.setConsumerKey(config.twitter.consumerKey, config.twitter.consumerSecret);

var tweetData = {};

// Function to call twitter api, called by route
var callAPI = function(callback) {

  getAccessToken(callback());

  console.log('callAPI function loaded');
};

var getAccessToken = function(callback) {
  cb.__call(
    "oauth2_token",
    {},
    function (reply, err) {
      var accessToken;
      console.log('1. response received');
      if (err) {
          console.log("error response or timeout exceeded" + err.error);
          return;
      }
      if (reply) {
          console.log('2. twitter: reply received');
          console.log(reply);
          accessToken = reply.access_token;
          getUserTweets(accessToken, callback);
      }
    }
  );
};

var getUserTweets = function(authToken, callback) {
  console.log('passed accessToken');
  console.log(authToken);
  console.log(typeof callback);
  cb.__call(
    "users_show",
    params,
    function (reply, rate, err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Error in showing user or timed out" + err.error);
      }
      if (reply) {
        console.log("received user's tweet");
        var newTweetData = {
          screen_name: reply.screen_name,
          name: reply.name,
          status_text: reply.status.text,
          status_date: reply.status.created_at,
          status_retweets: reply.status.retweet_count,
          status_favourites: reply.status.favorite_count
        };
        console.log(newTweetData);
        // final callback to set a variable
        console.log(typeof callback);
        setTweetData(newTweetData, callback);
        // console.log('getUserTweets callback');
        // callback;

      }
    }
  );
};

var setTweetData = function(newTweetData, callback) {
  if(!newTweetData) {
    return 'variable is a string, not function';
  }

  tweetData = newTweetData;
  console.log('tweet data has been set');
  console.log(callback);
  callback(tweetData);
};




module.exports = { params, callAPI };
```

Not sure what the proper way is to pass that callback from my route, through to the end of my function chain so that my res.send() triggers once I have acquired the twitter data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change callApi method to pass "callback" as parameter and not call it.

```
var callAPI = function(callback) {

  getAccessToken(callback);
  // and not getAccessToken(callback());

  console.log('callAPI function loaded');
};
```

The difference is, in you code you are calling the callback just after authentication.

After my change, you pass the callback to **getUserTweets** function, and it will call the callback after tweets fetched.

Comment: YES finally it works. So does `getAccessToken(callback())` call callback() at the end of getAccessToken? I thought I had to trigger the callback inside the function before it got executed? Thank you for spending time on this, next step refactoring!